# setting the path for jwplayer.swf

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6

jwplayer 6 loads the jwplayer.flash.swf file based on the current jwplayer.js location which works in most cases. I however load jwplayer 6(.7.4071) using a minification and concatenation mechanism in my CMS that rewrites the URL for loading jwplayer.js to this:

```
 /global/js/minifier.js?uris=/global/js/jwplayer6.7.4071/jwplayer.js
```

This result in loading the jwplayer.flash.swf file through the minifier as well:

```
/global/js/minifier.js?uris=/global/js/jwplayer6.7.4071/jwplayer.flash.swf
```

This does not work of course: it crashes the minification component because you cannot 'minify' swf files. I tried explicitly setting the location of the swf file using the `flashplayer` and `base` options, but the first one has been deprecated in jwplayer 6 and the second one does not seem to work.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You can use the flashplayer and html5player options to set the location of both of these files now.

Comment: Hi where do you put the jwplayer.flash.swf file and how to do refer / link to it?